# How to get last day of a given month for a given year with moment

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm working on an Angular project. I need last day of a given month for a given year using moment. But there are some limitations. I don't have a full date in a proper `mm-dd-yyyy`, etc format. And also that data types are `any`. We'll have two input fields, one for the `month` and the other for `year`. Then on click of `Get last day` button I should get the last day in numeric format, because I've to perform some arithmetic on that later. See it's very simple:

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="month"/>
<input [(ngModel)]="year"/>
<button (click)="getLastDate()">Get last date</button>

<p>Last date of {{month}}/{{year}} is: </p>
```

And this is what I want:

> If month=12, year=1990; then lastDate should be 31
>
> If month=11, year=2020; then lastDate should be 30

Care should be taken for leap years:

> If month=2, year=2020; then lastDate should be 29
>
> If month=2, year=2021; then lastDate should be 28

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { Component, DoCheck, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timeselector',
  templateUrl: './timeselector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timeselector.component.css']
})
export class TimeselectorComponent {

  month=12;
  year=1990;

  lastDate="";

  getLastDate() {
  // logic to get last date of the given month NOT WORKING

  // const fromDate = moment(this.month, 'MM-DD-YYYY', true);
  // const toDate = moment(this.year, 'MM-DD-YYYY', true);
  // const customStartMonth = moment(fromDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY').month();
  // const customStartYear = moment(fromDate).year();
  // const customendMonth = moment(toDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY').month();
  // const customendYear = moment(toDate).year();

  }
}
```

I've tried many answers but they are different from mine. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqbh19) also. Please help me. Is it even doable with moment or I'll have to write some custom code of my own. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your demo :

```
moment(this.year + '-' + this.month).endOf('month').format('DD')
```

Comment: I tried this. It worked. can explain the answer so that I can justify to my team lead.

Answer (score 2):

Get the first day of next month and then [subtract](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/02-subtract/) 1 day from it.

```js
let month = 2,
  year = 2020,
  lastDate = "";

var now = moment(`${month}/1/${year}`).add(1,'months').subtract(1, 'days');

alert(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be this:

```js
const getLastDay = (year, month) => moment().year(year).month(month - 1).daysInMonth();

console.log(getLastDay(2020, 2));
console.log(getLastDay(2021, 2));
console.log(getLastDay(1990, 12));
console.log(getLastDay(2020, 11));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution is also correct. I tried this also. :-)  But for now I'm accepting the above answer as it is more easier to me. However, I'll show both the answers to my tech lead, so, I may change my vote later. Thanks a lot for this answer:-)